# Creating Shapes with for loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops, shapes

I'm a newbie to Java and I need to print out shapes using for loops.

1)

```
*
***
*****
***
*
```

2)

```
*****
****
***
**
*
*
**
***
****
******
```

I really would appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Please post your code. 2. Please post what exactly you expect.

Comment: I particularly get bent when a solved problem, asking about algorithm discovery, suddenly doesn't have enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, first you need to be able to describe the pattern.

If you can reliably draw the "next" shape for the integer input, then you know the pattern.

Then you think of which parts of the pattern are counted items (3 stars, then a blank, for example).  Once you identify the counted items, you make a relationship between that count and the number one typed in.

Finally, for each counted item you write a for loop that, within it's block, contains code to output one item.  The control structure of the for loop should make sure that the count is exercised the correct number of times.

For each item where the count is 1, you may omit the for loop and simple print the item out directly.

--- Examples --

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

Thought process:

1. The first line is 5 spaces then a star.
2. The second line is 4 spaces then 3 stars.
3. The third line is 3 spaces then 5 starts.
4. I see a pattern, the first line is (5 spaces - the line number)

   ```
   for (int spaces = 0; spaces < 5 - line_number; spaces++) {
     print(" ");
   }
   ```
5. That other pattern, was (counting stars) 1, 3, 5, 7, 9.
6. The pattern is one of differences 3-1 = 2, 5-3 = 2, 7-5=2, etc.
7. I need to start with one star, and add two stars per line.

   ```
   for (int stars = 1; stars < 1 + 2 * line_number; stars++) {
      print("*");
   }
   ```
8. Now I need a loop for the lines

   ```
   for (int line_number = 0; line_number < 5; line_number++) {
      print("\n");
   }
   ```
9. Now I'll put it all together

   ```
   for (int line_number = 0; line_number < 5; line_number++) {
     for (int spaces = 0; spaces < 5 - line_number; spaces++) {
       print(" ");
     }
     for (int stars = 1; stars < 1 + 2 * line_number; stars++) {
       print("*");
     }
     print("\n");
   }
   ```

Comment: +1 for giving a worked example of how this type of problem is solved, so OP can use this to then learn how to solve their task.

Comment: @ReadyPlayer2 Thanks.  I've tutored plenty of people, and the first rule I used is "if it's school work, I'm crafting a similar problem" because tutoring is even less fun when it is just doing someone else's homework :)